# Issues Printing to CSV file

Tags: php, csv, io, output

I am printing directly to a CSV file so that the user can save the results of their query, in this case reproducing a report from the archives.

My data is two bits of info- the title, and date, which I'm trying to add to the front of the file, and then the lines of the report.

```
$f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
// loop over the input array

    // Add report title
    fputcsv($f, $reportname, $delimiter);

    //add the date
    fputcsv($f, $reportdate, $delimiter);

//add report text
foreach ($array as $line) { 
    // generate csv lines from the inner arrays
    fputcsv($f, $line, $delimiter); 
}
```

What happens is that the text from the array in the loop gets printed into the file- but that the first two lines don't. For the life of me, I can't figure it out.

Any suggestions would be welcome, thanks.

Comment: $reportname,$reportdate both set and are arrays? could test `fputcsv($f, array('nameeeeeeeeeeeee'), $delimiter);`

Comment: That solved it. Thank you. That's perfect.

Comment: im confused by what solved it based on the answer you selected

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me select your answer because it was a comment, not an answer- so I tried to put your suggestions as an answer myself (and attribute it to you). I think the other person's suggestion may also work. (I'm new here, I'm not sure how the selection thing works. God know there's multiple ways to do things)

Answer (score 1):

This was solved, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/8011997/rtfm. 
The solution was- the values I wanted to send to the file had to be arrays. So I cast them as arrays- (array)$var_Name- and it worked perfectly.

So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$file='Statement '.$date.".csv";
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'";');
```

then just echo out the contents in CSV format.

```
$ct = count($data);
$ctr = 0;
foreach($datas as $data) {

    //workaround for removing quotes
        $val = explode(",", $data);

        //create a seperate function for this 
        $cv = count($val);
        $cvi = 0;
        foreach ($val as $k => $v){
            echo $v;
            //append comma except for last word
            $cvi++;
            if($cvi < $cv)
                echo ",";
        }

        $ctr++;
        if ($ctr < $ct) echo "\n";//except for last line terminate with \n

    }
```

I was having similar issue and got this from SO itself. Been using this for a long time. This is useful if you want to keep the formatting

Comment: I didn't try this method, because the other solution worked and required less changes to the code- but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use fwrite function when fputcsv fails.